# Постраничный вывод данных

Tags: java, база-данных, jsp, servlet

Добрый день, есть один вопросик, добавил в дао метод с переменной `count`(нужно для подсчета страниц), в контроллере его вызвал `request.setAttribute("counts", dao.getCounts())` в `requst` `count` передало, пытаюсь на jsp его получить таким образом `<%if (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) >=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("counts"))){%>` но почему-то оно не передает на страницу именно `count`, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: просто ${counts} вставьте на jsp

Comment: Если вам нужна конструкция if на jsp то можно делать так  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core_1_1" %> - добавить на jsp страницу
 
            <c:choose><%--Это конструкция if...else--%>
                <c:when test="${myLogins.size() > 0}">
                    <%-- Do somthing --%>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    Нет программ
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>

Comment: @Adrenal1ne 
спасибо, очень полезная информация, а еще вопрос, можно ли как-то for заменить?

Comment: <c:forEach items="${myLogins}" var="log"> //myLogins - коллекция
                        
                        ${log} - отдельный элемент коллекции, обрабатывай как хочешь
                    </c:forEach>

Comment: полный список тегов http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm . В поисковике пишите "jstl <имя тега>"

Comment: спасибо большое, буду пробовать)

Comment: @Adrenal1ne нужна помощь, заменил данную конструкцию `<%                    
for (int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) - 2; 
i <= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) + 2;i++) {if(i > 0){%><li class="li1"><a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=<%=i%>><%=i%></a></li><% }}%>` 
на такую `<c:forEach var = "i" begin = "${page-2}" end = "${page+2}">
              <c:choose><c:when test="${i > 0}"><li class="li1"><a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=${i}>${i}</a></li></c:when></c:choose></c:forEach>` что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в контроллере вы его сохраняете как атрибут, а в джсп читаете почему то из параметров. попробуйте `request.getAttribute("counts")`

Comment: пробовал так, оно писало что `int` не может преобразовать в `string`, сейчас пытаюсь JSTL тегами сделать, потом еще раз попробую данный вариант

Comment: просто убрать Integer.parseInt за ненадобностью, вы ведь и так Integer в атрибут садите.